# Pronouncing years in Spanish

Tags: pronunciación, números

In English 1886 would be pronounced "eighteen-eighty six." In Spanish, is there something similar? Or do people outright say:

> El año mil ochocientos ochenta y seis

Comment: We say mil ochocientos ochenta y seis

Comment: The only shortening of years I have ever heard were simply a decade as in "the 80's" would be "las ochentas"

Comment: @joseph4tw, I've never heard _las ochentas_.  The only way I've ever heard it is _los ochenta_ (masculine and number sans _s_).

Comment: @guifa apologies, I meant to write "los ochentas." And as I said, I have *heard* it said that way. I never learned this in any academic context, so this way of saying it might be limited to a Colombian way of expressing "the 80s." When you herad it as *los ochenta* (singularity seems to be the only difference), is it based on any academia? Or maybe from a particular country/region?

Comment: @joseph4tw I interact with academics from all over, and haven't heard it pluralized, but it's certainly possible in some regions that it is. But the DPD in its entry for _década_ gives _los años ochenta_, _la década de ochenta_ and _la década del ochenta_ for what the English _the eighties_, but specifically recommends against any plural form of the multiple of ten.

Comment: @guifa thanks for the clarification. The way you explain it does make sense. Now I know the correct way of saying it :) thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in Spanish there is generally no way to abbreviate the years. The only time it is used is referring to the years in the XX century. Example:

> Do you remember that concert back in eighty-nine?
>
> Recuerdas ese concierto en el ochenta y nueve?

Other than in that case, the full year is pronounced. Even for this century's years.

> Do you remember that concert in two thousand and five?
>
> Recuerdas ese concierto en el dos mil cinco?

Comment: The question is not about abbreviations in years, but saying years.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. In my answer I was also talking about the way to say it verbally ;)

Comment: @JoulSauron: "Nineteen ninety-eight" and "Two thousand four" are verbal abbreviations in English. The question is asking if this is possible in Spanish.

Comment: @Flimzy I've always thought that they were the actual ways of saying years. Do you mean then that pronouncing the whole number in a year is correct?

Comment: @JoulSauron: The longer forms are correct, too. For example "Nineteen hundred and ninety-eight." We do the same thing with addresses.  The address "1998 Somestreet" could be "Nineteen ninety-eight somestreet," "Nineteen hundred ninety-eight Somestreet" or "One thousand nine hundred and ninety-eight Somestreet." The last form is rarely, if ever, used with years in modern writing or speech, though.

Answer (score 2):

In Puerto Rico, we use a short form like "mil ocho ochenta y seis"

Comment: Also in Argentina - but only coloquially

Answer (score 1):

The way to say years is the same as it would be a normal number, there is no distinction whether the number is a quantity or a year. So you are right with your example:

> El año 1886.
>
> El año mil ochocientos ochenta y seis.

Comment: That's right. I've also heard argentinians saying 'mil ocho ochenta y seis', but I'm not sure how common this pronunciation is.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake I will add that in Spanish there is no "shortcut" to say numbers larger than 1000. For example: 1200 can be "one thousand two hundred" or "twelve hundred". There is no such thing in Spanish. That number, as a year or as a number, will always be "mil doscientos".