# Are there alternative ways to read numbers aloud in Spanish?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, números

The obvious way to read a number aloud is to read it as though it had been spelled out in words rather than given as digits. So 245 is read aloud as *doscientos cuarenta y cinco*.

What about numbers which are just identifiers like Boeing 737, hotel rooms, numbers in catalogues like Bach's cantata Wachet auf BWV 140. Is it optional whether to read them as a number or to spell out the digits? So would I say Boeing *siete tres siete*

Comment: Note that we already have an answer about telephone numbers https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/why-are-telephone-numbers-sometimes-verbally-expanded specifically.

Comment: I guess the answer to this would be subjective and with lots of variations depending on the subject and region so I won't put the following in an answer. I read those like. Boing _siete treinta y siete_, Bach BMV _ciento cuarenta_, Usually In hotel rooms the first digits are the floor number so for room 1409 we read those _catorce cero nueve_

Comment: Well, in fact I do say "Boeing siete-tres-siete". But I also say "Airbus A cuatrocientos M" for Airbus A400M. So I guess it depends...

Comment: The answer is of course yes. As to whether there's a general rule or tendency, I don't know but it would be interesting to research

Comment: There is also one question about years https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2468/pronouncing-years-in-spanish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do have choices.

1. As though it were quantifying something: *doscientos cuarenta y cinco* (even though it isn't).
2. Digit by digit: dos cuatro cinco.
3. Combination: dos cuarenta y cinco.

If there's no quantified meaning, the most common approach is to use whatever will be succinct (small number of syllables), hence siete-tres-siete vs. Uno-cuarenta.

Bonus information: if you want to talk about a bus number (bus route), here is what is customary in Mexico at least:

> Voy a tomar la Ruta Uno.